# Ansible で、 ssh に利用している IP アドレスを変数として利用したい

Tags: ansible

Ansible で記述を行っていく中で、例えば自身の IP アドレスをサーバー設定ファイルに記述したくなったとします。これはどうやったら実現できるでしょうか。

特に、 ssh に利用したホスト(のIP)を ansible は知ることができるはずなので、それを変数として利用する方法がないかどうか知りたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Variables — Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-complex-variable-data)

こちらに書いてますが `{{ foo }}` という書式で変数にアクセスできます。
IPアドレスを表す変数は [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-of-the-ansible-variables) によると `ansible -m setup hostname` で調べることが出来ます。

試しに実行してみましたら次のように表示されました。

```
$ ansible -m setup localhost
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
       (略)
        "ansible_eth0": {
            "active": true,
            "device": "eth0",
            "ipv4": {
                "address": "10.0.2.15",
                "broadcast": "10.0.2.255",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
                "network": "10.0.2.0"
            },
            "ipv6": [
                {
                    "address": "fe80::a00:27ff:fef5:dcf9",
                    "prefix": "64",
                    "scope": "link"
                }
            ],
            "macaddress": "08:00:27:f5:dc:f9",
            "module": "pcnet32",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "pciid": "0000:00:03.0",
            "promisc": false,
            "type": "ether"
        },
        (略)
```

これを参照するには `{{ ansible_eth0["ipv4"]["address"] }}` または `{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}` と書きます。